# Color is wrong when converting CMYK images to RGB using imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, rgb, cmyk

I had a bunch of images uploaded as cmyk and I needed to convert them to rgb.

I used the line

```
exec("convert -colorspace RGB " . $myfile . " " . $myfile);
```

But the color is way off (example, a brownish color looks greenish).

I'm not sure why it's doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
-colorspace sRGB
```

Comment: It's a little better, but still not the actual colors. It has dark green where it was brown and light red where it had dark red.